# How to trigger a change on a checkbox or click a row to select a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, checkbox, html-table

I have a table with checkboxes in the first column.

Rows can be selected either by (a) checking the checkbox or (b) clicking on the row. Selected rows should be highlighted.

My problem is I can get either one to work separately, but not both together. Here is what I have:

```
 // click on row      
 $('table tbody tr').click( function() {
    $(this).find( "th input:checkbox").trigger('change');
    // $(this).find( "th input:checkbox").trigger('click');
});

 // change listener
 $('.tr input:checkbox').live( "change", function () {
    console.log("change triggered");

  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  if ( $(this).attr('checked') == "checked" ) {
          row.addClass( 'ui-btn-hover-c' ).removeClass( 'row_selected ui-btn-up-e' )
          } else {
              row.addClass('row_selected ui-btn-hover-e' ).removeClass( "ui-btn-up-c");
          }
  });
```

I thought I would just route the clicks on TR into the checkbox change handler, so there is only one place that checks for selected rows and handles class addition/removal.

However I can't get it to work. The above somehow creates an endless loop and I have no idea how to get it working properly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a listener on a row, and another listener on a checkbox within the row then both of these will be fired when you click on the checkbox unless you stop the event propagation. i.e. The click on the checkbox is also a click on the tr.

Normally you would use `event.stopPropagation();` but you cannot use this on the `live()` method as the event will have already propagated.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

In your case, if you can change from using `live` to using `click` you could then use:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

To prevent the click on the checkbox from triggering the click on the table row.

Comment: ah. you are right. clicking the checkbox also clicks the row. There's my loop. Ok. Thanks. I will try to work something out.